# Add bleed using geometry

Tags: geometry, paper-size

I'm using a5paper size with extreport and geometry. Could you please tell me how to add a bleed of 2mm and keep things as they are.

```
 \usepackage[a5paper, 
             %hmargin = {3cm, .8in}, 
             left = 2.3cm,
             bottom=2.5cm,
             includefoot
             %right = 1cm,
             %width = 10.8cm,
             %height = 17cm
             ]
             {geometry}
```

Comment: "and keep things as they are": So you want to enlarge the paper by 2mm around all edges?

Comment: Yes... I want just that. I want to keep my layout the same centered with those 2-3mm on each size. The issue is that then I have to cut the paper and there is an error of 2-3 mm

Comment: At least in the width, I think there is a key for this “binding correction”, but in the height… I think not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set manually a `papersize` with the added 2mm each side, and then set the option `layout=a5paper` - that will be what you are working with after. Also you have to set `layouthoffset` and `layoutvoffset` to get the content centered on the page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={152mm,214mm},%instead of 148×210
    layout=a5paper,
    layouthoffset=2mm,
    layoutvoffset=2mm,
    left    = 2.3cm,
    bottom  = 2.5cm,
    includefoot,
    showframe
    ]
    {geometry}
\begin{document}
howdie
\end{document}
```